# Servlet showing no output

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-6

With the below page, I'm expecting to see my message `This page requires...` but all I'm seeing is a blank page (no errors).

```
package guest;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/guestExport"})
public class GuestExportServlet extends HttpServlet {

    //Injected DAO EJB
    @EJB GuestDao guestDao;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("This page requires a POST");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("This page is a POST");
    }
}
```

Any obvious problems here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obvious problem: System.out writes to the local console, not the web page you want to display. Everything you want to deliver to the requesting client has to be written to the `HttpServletResponse` object.